# C# control not going into the method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, function, methods

I am trying to call a private method from another private method like this

```
UploadFeeScheduleToDb(147, finalPath);
```

Method definition:

```
void UploadFeeScheduleToDb(int UploadID, string UploadFilePath)
{
    DataSet CSVData = CSVToDataSet(UploadFilePath);
}
```

The problem is that the C# control is coming to the method call but not going inside it. I added breakpoints like this:
[image]

As you can see, the control is reaching the breakpoint but it's not reaching to the second breakpoint inside that method. It's just skipping to `lblMsg.Text...` statement without any exceptions in output window.

I tried cleaning solution and rebuilding. Also, I passed constants or magic values to the method. But no luck. I don't know what is happening?

Comment: Perhaps code optimization is turned on and the method is inlined. Perhaps an exception occurs, but it is not in your user code. Try enabling breaking on all exceptions.

Comment: Can you add try catch around your code that is calling UploadFreeScheduleToDb and just se if it throws any exceptions.

Comment: are you sure about there is no overloaded UploadFeeScheduleToDb method and id is type of int and finalPath is type of string. ? @aishwarya-shiva

Comment: Odd, but a few things to try: is finalPath a field/local variable, or a property? If the latter, it might be its getter that is causing an issue. Second - in the active Build Configuration, is that project actually set to build? If not, the code might no longer match the binary, but it will still seem to build and run fine. Lastly try stick a try-catch around that line - does anything throw?

Comment: @Silvermind Yes code optimization was the issue. I turned it off from project settings and it's now coming inside the method. Thank you so much. Can you add it as an answer with more detail?

Comment: "code optimization was the issue" - because that method only assigns to a local variable. It does absolutely nothing.

Comment: @HenkHolterman nice point. Can you add it as an answer? It's really something that should be considered when using code optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Silvermind and @HenkHolterman said, the `UploadFeeScheduleToDb` method is not doing anything productive except assigning the value to its local variable, the C# compiler will ignore this method when Code Optimization feature is turned on. I think this is called [Dead Code Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination). Correct me if I am wrong.